# AJAX update for Spring <form:select> element

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, auto-update

I'm using Spring MVC for a project. In it, on a particular page, I'm using the Spring form tags to display an ArrayList added to the model in the controller as below:

```
<form:select path="myList">
    <form:options items="${listElements}"/>
</form:select>
```

Now, `listElements` may be edited from another page (a child window), so I want `myList` to be auto updated every 2 sec or so. As of now I am refreshing the parent window when an element is added; the form in the parent page however has other fields in which the user simply keys in data, so  a full refresh resets that data as it has not yet been posted. As such, I want to use AJAX to update just my `form:select` element every 2 seconds.

How can I do this?

**Note:** I am an AJAX noob. I went through a few similar posts on SO and elsewhere, but sadly I was not able to figure it out. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: do you have access to jquery or any other library

Comment: @ArunPJohny: To JQuery, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for! :)

In case someone else finds it useful in the future, what I did is as follows:

1. Gave an `id` to my `<form:select>`:
2. Created `reloadlist.html`, a page with only a copy of the relevant `<form:select>`.
3. Added the following script:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function Ajax(){
> var xmlHttp;
>     try{    
>         xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
>     }catch (e){
>         try{
>             xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
>         }catch (e){
>             try{
>                 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>             }catch (e){
>                 alert("No AJAX!?");
>                 return false;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
>         document.getElementById('ReloadList').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
>         setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
>     }
>     xmlHttp.open("GET","reloadlist.html",true);
>     xmlHttp.send(null);
> }
> window.onload=function(){
>     setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
> }
> </script>
> ```

This probably isn't a very good way to get this done, but it worked. Better answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

1.Add Id attribute in select element.

2.Add ajax method handler in mvc controller which returns arrayList (I would prefer return json object).

3.Fire ajax call in jquery/javascript

JSP code:

```
<head>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/form.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/1.6/jquery.js" />"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var interval =2000;
        setInterval("getServerData()",interval);
        function getServerData(){
            $.getJSON("/MyApp/data/jsonList", function(response){ 
                $("#selectBox option").remove(); 
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                        options += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
                        $("#selectBox").html(options);
                    });
            });
        }
        </script>           
</head>
<body>
    <form:form id="form" method="post">
        <select id="selectBox">
        <select>
    </form:form>    
</body>
```

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/data/jsonList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> getDataList() {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("option1");
    myList.add("option2");
    myList.add("option3");
    myList.add("option4");
    return myList;
}
```

if you plan to user jquery check 
[Updating select box options via jQuery AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040219/updating-select-box-options-via-jquery-ajax)

[Good read: Spring ajax 3.0](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) page.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a simply example?

Comment: I had to drop form prefix as it forces me to write path attribute and other. however I think it can be handled this example is just to show how it can be done.

Comment: I can only try it out after the weekend now, but this seems right to me anyway. I'll let you know if this works out for me; thanks in advance!